# How to automatically uncheck the action check of a parent permission, when all the actions of the subpermissions are unchecked

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working with react and typescript, and I have the following problem.

Currently unchecking the parent permission check with a delay action, which is wrong.

I share my complete code so you can analyze it and have more context.

```
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AickTrHAuy48yeAf5tM1bMrFfGpmZA?e=KWvy3y
file: TagsManagement.ts
```

Initially from the API I get the following JSON when I click on a user:

```
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AickTrHAuy48yeAf5tM1bMrFfGpmZA?e=KWvy3y
file: permissions original.JSON
```

Then with the "organizePermission" function I organize the received JSON to plaster it over my permissions table which is in the function: "renderHierarchicalPermissions", this would be the new object of my permissions:

```
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AickTrHAuy48yeAf5tM1bMrFfGpmZA?e=KWvy3y
file: organizedPermissions.JSON
```

The problem occurs when I uncheck all the checks for the actions of the subpermissions, since the check for the READ action of the parent permission should be unchecked there, but it is not unchecked, and it waits for me to do another interaction with some action so that it just reads there. There are no actions marked and the check has just been removed, a procedure that is wrong, this happens in the "handleActionChange" function which is executed every time a checkbox is clicked.

```
  const handleActionChange = (
    permission: Permission,
    actionId: number,
    isChecked: boolean
  ) => {
    // Verificar si la acción está presente en los datos de la API
    const isActionEnabled = permission.module_actions.some(
      (action) => action.module_action_id === actionId
    );

    if (!isActionEnabled) {
      // La acción no está habilitada, no permitir cambios en el checkbox
      return;
    }

    // Actualizar el estado de la acción en el subpermiso
    const updatedPermissions = permissions.map((p) => {
      if (p.module_id === permission.module_id) {
        const updatedActions = p.module_actions.map((a) => {
          if (a.module_action_id === actionId) {
            return { ...a, active: isChecked };
          }
          return a;
        });

        // Buscar el permiso padre
        const parentPermission = findPermission(
          organizedPermissions,
          permission.module_parent_id
        );

        // Verificar si el permiso padre existe
        if (parentPermission) {
          let isAnyActionActive = false;
          // Recorre todos los subpermisos para verificar si al menos una acción está activa
          Object.values(parentPermission?.subPermissions || {}).forEach((subPermission) => {
            isAnyActionActive = isAnyActionActive || subPermission.module_actions.some((action) => action.active);
          });
          // Actualiza el estado de lectura del permiso padre
          parentPermission.module_actions.forEach((action) => {
            if (action.module_action_id === actionIdMap["Leer"]) {
              action.active = isAnyActionActive;
            }
          });
        }

        return { ...p, module_actions: updatedActions };
      }
      return p;
    });

    // setPermissions(() => [...updatedPermissions]);
    setPermissions(() => [...updatedPermissions]);
  };
```

The erroneous procedure can also be viewed at the following URL: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AickTrHAuy48yeAeRRwS113hz98lLA?e=TlVgj6

The correct operation is as follows: if the parent permission has 2 subpermissions, such as 'ADMINISTRATION', and each subpermission has 4 actions, they make a total of 8 actions. If all actions are unchecked, the READ action of the parent permission must be unchecked, when I remove the last check from the action of some subpermission. But if no action is marked, and I check some permission, the check for the read action of the parent permission must be activated.

Inside the "HandleActionChange" function I replaced the following:

```
if (parentPermission) {
          let isAnyActionActive = false;
        
          // Recorre todos los subpermisos para verificar si al menos una acción está activa
          Object.values(parentPermission?.subPermissions || {}).forEach((subPermission) => {
            isAnyActionActive = isAnyActionActive || subPermission.module_actions.some((action) => action.active);
          });
        
          // Actualiza el estado de lectura del permiso padre
          parentPermission.module_actions.forEach((action) => {
            if (action.module_action_id === actionIdMap["Leer"]) {
              action.active = isAnyActionActive;
            }
          });
        }
```

By the following code fragment:

```
let totalInactives = 0;
        let totalActions = 0;
        Object.values(parentPermission?.subPermissions || {}).forEach(subPermission => {
          totalInactives += subPermission.module_actions.filter(action => !action.active).length
          totalActions += subPermission.module_actions.length
        })
        if(totalInactives === totalActions){
          parentPermission?.module_actions.forEach(action => {
            if (action.module_action_id === actionIdMap["Leer"]) {
              action.active = false;
            }
          });
        }
        if((totalActions - totalInactives) > 0) {
          parentPermission?.module_actions.forEach(action => {
            if (action.module_action_id === actionIdMap["Leer"]) {
              action.active = true;
            }
          });
        }
```

But I still continue with the error mentioned and in the video found in the attached URL.

I need that when unchecking the last action of a subpermission it is automatically removed and at that moment the check for the action of the parent permission is removed. And what if the actions of the subpermissions are unchecked, and I activate any of them, automatically and at that moment the check for the parent permission action is marked.